# Vue.js turning event capturing on / off

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue.js in my project.

For example an event listener has an third option called `capture` like this:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(){}, true);
```

Is it able to turn the capture on / off with Vue.js at '@click'?

Comment: Vuejs has wonderful *documentation* - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers - it's actually known for how good its documentation is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with the help of Event Modifiers it's possible to do it.
You just need to add `.capture` modifier with your `@click`. Something like this:

```
<div @click.capture="myFunction()">Content</div>
```

For more info read the great documentation of vue itself [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

@Jaromanda X has already mentioned it.